# Using AMI to send Fax

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am wondering if it is possible to create a AMI based script which will send a fax. My Asterisk currently creates a file in the **/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing** which has the following content

```
Channel: Local/2135552222@from-inside/n
MaxRetries: 12
RetryTime: 300
WaitTime: 60
Context: tl-faxsend
Extension: SendFax
Priority: 1
Set: FILENAME=/tmp/3444-2019-01-1-19-42-13.tiff
Set: STATIONID=1234567890ID
Set: CONFSUCCESS=1
Set: EMAILADDR=demo@acme.com
Set: REMOTENUMBER=2135552222
Set: MYEXTEN=3444
```

using that file the fax send fine, but if i use **Action: Originate** in the AMI and pass this info i get the error that **Message: Extension does not exist.**

What am i missing here ?

Comment: Does anything come out at the command line for Asterisk? What extension is being used when originating the request to send a fax? Is that extension defined in sip.conf?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with command line. If i take the above call file and drop it in the asterisk outgoing folder, it sends the fax just fine. If i try to put the above as a AMI Originate i get that the Extension SendFax is not found. SendFax is not a extension but the Asterisk SendFax() function

Comment: How are you calling AMI? Consider also change Extension: SendFax to Exten: SendFax. 
Doc https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+ManagerAction_Originate

Comment: I am using the asterisk-ami-client in nodeJS to call this via the client.action(). It works fine with other originating scripts.

Comment: This fiddle  originated a call without a problemhttps://jsfiddle.net/921twkco/

Comment: Viewing the output at the Asterisk CLI might give you some clues about what is failing. See the documentation at https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Command+Line+Interface

Comment: Changing Extension: to Exten: fixed one problem but i am still having issue passing arguments like in CallFile to the code like for example.
FILENAME : '/var/spool/asterisk/fax/localhost-1546395489.347.tif'
In the console i see now that it is missing the Arguments like File name
[2019-01-02 18:28:03] WARNING[7781][C-00000232]: res_fax.c:2677 sendfax_exec: SendFAX requires an argument (filename[&filename[&filename]],options])

Comment: Post the content of client.action(). See https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-manager-api-action-originate/

Comment: You are missing debug stage. Dump your action, enable asterisk debug mode, see how asterisk parse your input. But debug is OFFTOPIC on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more reading up on this and debug i found the source of my problem. For one as Marcos pointed out, the call file uses Extension vs the AMI expects Exten. After that change i was able to call the script but i was missing the set variables. So to make this whole thing work the AMI call looks like this

```
Action: 'Originate',
         ActionID: '9CF82D29-C0CD-43A7-8622-18D5FD7F6A59',
         Channel: 'Local/213XXXXXXX@from-inside',
         MaxRetries: 12 ,
         RetryTime: 300 ,
         WaitTime: 60 ,
         Context: 'tl-faxsend',
         Exten: 'SendFax',
         Priority: 1,
         Async: 'true',
         Variable: 'FILENAME=/var/spool/asterisk/fax/localhost-1546479385.466.tif,EMAILADDR=tom@acme.com,STATIONID=213XXXXXXX,REMOTENUMBER=213XXXXXXX,MYEXTEN=3444',
```